# How to convert from C #define with functions

Tags: delphi

I have C header with defines like

```
#define tds_accept      accept
#define tds_getpeername getpeername
#define tds_getsockopt  getsockopt
#define tds_getsockname getsockname
#define tds_recvfrom    recvfrom
```

where I should convert defines to Delphi and assign functions (from Winsock2). I tried both `const` and `type`

```
type
  tds_accept      = accept;
  tds_getpeername = getpeername;
  tds_getsockopt  = getsockopt;
  tds_getsockname = getsockname;
  tds_recvfrom    = recvfrom;
```

and have errors `E2007 Constant or type identifier expected` or `E2035 Not enough actual parameters`
Is it possible to do it with Delphi?

Comment: AFAIR delphi has no macros support, you can either go with pointers to functions or external macro processor: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893989/delphi-7-macro-preprocessor-support

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use typed variables instead, eg:

```
var
  tds_accept      : function(s: TSocket; addr: PSockAddr; addrlen: PInteger): TSocket; stdcall;
  tds_getpeername : function(s: TSocket; var name: TSockAddr; var namelen: Integer): Integer; stdcall;
  tds_getsockopt  : function(s: TSocket; level, optname: Integer; optval: PAnsiChar; var optlen: Integer): Integer; stdcall;
  tds_getsockname : function(s: TSocket; var name: TSockAddr; var namelen: Integer): Integer; stdcall;
  tds_recvfrom    : function(s: TSocket; var Buf; len, flags: Integer; var from: TSockAddr; var fromlen: Integer): Integer; stdcall;

initialization
  tds_accept      := accept;
  tds_getpeername := getpeername;
  tds_getsockopt  := getsockopt;
  tds_getsockname := getsockname;
  tds_recvfrom    := recvfrom;
```

Or:

```
type
  lpfn_accept      = function(s: TSocket; addr: PSockAddr; addrlen: PInteger): TSocket; stdcall;
  lpfn_getpeername = function(s: TSocket; var name: TSockAddr; var namelen: Integer): Integer; stdcall;
  lpfn_getsockopt  = function(s: TSocket; level, optname: Integer; optval: PAnsiChar; var optlen: Integer): Integer; stdcall;
  lpfn_getsockname = function(s: TSocket; var name: TSockAddr; var namelen: Integer): Integer; stdcall;
  lpfn_recvfrom    = function(s: TSocket; var Buf; len, flags: Integer; var from: TSockAddr; var fromlen: Integer): Integer; stdcall;

var
  tds_accept      : lpfn_accept       = accept;
  tds_getpeername : lpfn_getpeername  = getpeername;
  tds_getsockopt  : lpfn_getsockopt   = getsockopt;
  tds_getsockname : lpfn_getsockname  = getsockname;
  tds_recvfrom    : lpfn_recvfrom     = recvfrom;
```

Answer (score 0):

Delphi does not have a pre-processor. So you typically find different ways to solve problems that are handled in C/C++ with the pre-processor. Personally, I think I'd use load time linking like this:

```
function tds_accept(...): TSocket; external dllname name 'accept';
```

and so on.